# Inverse image of image of an ideal under quotient.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$.Then define $q:R\to R/I$ by $q(x)=x+I$.Let $J$ be an ideal of $R$,then our professor told us that $q^{-1} (q(J))=I+J$.I am not sure how this is true.Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just show a two sided inclusion. If $x=i+j\in I+J$ then we have:

$q(x)=i+j+I=j+I=q(j)\in q(J)$

And so $x\in q^{-1}(q(J))$.

Conversely, suppose $x\in q^{-1}(q(J))$, i.e $q(x)\in q(J)$. That means there is some $j\in J$ such that $q(x)=q(j)$, i.e $x+I=j+I$. By definition this means $x-j\in I$. Hence there is some $i\in I$ such that $x-j=i$. And then $x=i+j\in I+J$.

Answer (score 1):

Just stare at it for long enough until it clicks.

The ideal $q(J)$ of $R/I$ is $\{j+I:j\in J\}$ since $q\colon R\to R/I$ is surjective.  Note that $q^{-1}(r+I)=r+I$ for all $r\in R$, and so
$$
q^{-1}(q(J))=q^{-1}(\{j+I:j\in J\})=\bigcup_{j\in J}(j+I)=J+I.
$$